# Move object on circle path

Tags: java, libgdx

My game is based on tiles, it's a board game where ships can move forward, left and right.

When a ship wants to move left or right, we have four parameters to set:

**Start point**: This is where my ship sprite is currently located at, this is the center of the tile its currently wants to move from.

**inbetween-point**: When a ship moves left or right, it needs to pass through a tile to turn to that direction (you will see the example in the preview)

**End point (target position)**: This is where the ship wants to move to.

**Center point between *start* and *end* points**: This is the center point between the starting and ending point, where we place our circle path.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

The first red point on bottom-left is our starting point.

The yellow point is the inbetween point

And the last red point on top-right side is our target location.

What I am trying to create is, make my ship move to the target position in a curve motion. Therfore I created a circle path, the center point of my ship's sprite must move in a straight line till it reaches the first point on the circle path, and then just continue moving on the path till it reaches the target position tile, once it does, it will move in a straight line till it reaches the target point.

Now the question is, how can I do this?

This is what I have so far:

```
    // Make sure that vessel has moves set to perform
    if (!vessel.getMoves().isEmpty()) {
        // Get the current move from the moves stack
        Move move = vessel.getMoves().peek();

        // Is the vessel currently performing move? if not, init a move!
        if (!vessel.isMoving()) {

            // the current rotation of the ship (either 0, 90, -90 or 180)
            float rotation = vessel.getSprite().getRotation();

            // the starting position
            Vector2 start = new Vector2(vessel.getSprite().getX(), vessel.getSprite().getY());

            // How much to add to X and Y to get the target positoon, based on current rotation of the ship (face)
            int moveX = move.getAddX(rotation) * TILE_SIZE;
            int moveY = move.getAddY(rotation) * TILE_SIZE;

            // get the end point (target pos)
            Vector2 end = new Vector2(vessel.getSprite().getX() + moveX, vessel.getSprite().getY() + moveY);

            // How much to add to x and y to get the inbetween position between start and end position
            int inbetweenX = move.getAddXInbetween(rotation) * TILE_SIZE;
            int inbetweenY = move.getAddYInbetween(rotation) * TILE_SIZE;

            Vector2 inbetween = new Vector2(start.x + inbetweenX, start.y + inbetweenY);


            vessel.setStart(start);
            vessel.setEnd(end);
            vessel.setInbetween(inbetween);

            vessel.setMoving(true);
        }
        else {
            // Starting position of the ship
            Vector2 start = vessel.getStart();
            // target position of the ship
            Vector2 end = vessel.getEnd();

            Vector2 inbetween = vessel.getInbetween();

            Vector2 middle = new Vector2((start.x + end.x) / 2, (start.y + end.y) / 2);

            renderer.rect(start.x + 32f, start.y + 32f, 1, 1);
            //renderer.rect(middle.x + 32f, middle.y + 32f, 1, 1);
            renderer.rect(end.x + 32f, end.y + 32f, 1, 1);

            renderer.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            renderer.rect(inbetween.x + 32f, inbetween.y + 32f, 1, 1);

            renderer.circle(middle.x + 32f, middle.y + 32f, (float) (TILE_SIZE / 2)); // radius is half of tile size
            // todo render and update coords/rotation here ...

        }
```

Comment: It looks like your sprite has a concept of direction. If so, this really is not as simple as going in a circle. If a ship is initially facing down and needs to travel up, it cannot do a 180 turn on the spot, it will need to start heading downwards (*away* from where its heading) in order to gradually turn around.

Comment: it cannot turn up when its facing down. the ship can do one move at time. either forward or left or right from current rotation

Comment: Look up Bezier curves.